# Login CSS style doesn't load instantly

Tags: customization

For some reason when changing the CSS of the login page it isn't loaded instantly, instead I can see the site content change after a very small delay when the page loads.
How come this happens?

What can I do to prevent this?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I clear all login CSS with this:

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', function() {
wp_dequeue_style( 'login' );
});
```

And load the new login CSS with this:

```
function theme_enqueue_login_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'login-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/stylesheets/admin/login-styles.css' );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_login_styles' );
```

I also tried using `login_head` with the same result.

Comment: Well how are you changing the CSS of the login page? Seems like an important detail to me.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that. See the updated question. I remove all CSS first, and later load new CSS with `login_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: Check your page source to see what stylesheets are loading. It sounds like some stylesheets are loading with styles you aren't expecting. The stylesheets loaded for a page are determined well before the page loads. WordPress does not remove any stylesheets after the page has started to render.